# What is rotating Tomcat log files?

Tags: logrotate, tomcat

One of our servers has Alfresco installed, and this is the content of `/opt/alfresco/tomcat/logs`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4.1K Jun 29 10:41 catalina.2015-06-29.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  352 Jul  1 18:36 catalina.2015-07-01.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.3M Jul 13 14:49 catalina.out
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun 29 10:38 host-manager.2015-06-29.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7.9K Jun 26 19:02 localhost.2015-06-26.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  33K Jun 29 10:39 localhost.2015-06-29.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  98M Jun 17 00:00 localhost_access_log.2015-06-16.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  98M Jun 18 00:00 localhost_access_log.2015-06-17.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  98M Jun 19 00:00 localhost_access_log.2015-06-18.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  98M Jun 20 00:00 localhost_access_log.2015-06-19.txt
(...)
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  75M Jul 12 00:00 localhost_access_log.2015-07-11.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  80M Jul 13 00:00 localhost_access_log.2015-07-12.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  85M Jul 14 00:00 localhost_access_log.2015-07-13.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  40M Jul 14 09:52 localhost_access_log.2015-07-14.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jun 29 10:38 manager.2015-06-29.log
```

Some process is obviously rotating the logs daily.  However, there's nothing operating on the Tomcat logs in `/etc/logrotate.d` -- or even in `/etc/cron.d/` or the crontab file.  Is there any setting in Tomcat or Alfresco that does this?

I'm asking because I want to add a "compress" option.  For now I've accomplished this result via a `find` one-liner script put as a daily cron job, but I like to do things in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat [rotates its log files itself](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Logging): by default at least `localhost_access_log_` (configured using an `AccessLogValve` in `server.xml`, look in `/opt/alfresco/tomcat/conf`) and the log files configured using a `FileHandler` in `logging.properties` (`catalina.out` and so on).

I'm not sure how you'd go about compressing the log files natively within Tomcat's logging framework, short of adding your own handler...